# Just learned to scrape data and store it in my DB but it only scrapes one object

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-scraping

First I am a novice, I'm still new to python and Django and I've just recently experimented with scraping my data and storing it in My database. I've got it to work kind of. It only scrapes one object and stores it. not multiple objects. Right now I am developing locally and trying to figure it out. I have it in a view like this

```
def practice(request):
    world = get_world_too()

    for entry in world:
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.save()

        template = "blog/post/noindex.html"
        context = {
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

and this is the function

```
        def get_world_too():
        url = 'http://www.example.org'
        html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')

        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
        entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
                    'src': box.img.get('src'),
                    'text': box.strong.a.text,
                    } for box in titles]
        return entries
```

it only scrapes and stores multiple objects If I refresh the page. But my function is set to 9, so I thought this would at least have nine objects stored in my database. and in the view I have a loop

```
for entry in world:
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.save()
```

so shouldn't the loop get all nine of the objects? Also I no this isn't the professional way to do this. As I sid I am just practicing with it. Ultimately I want to set up this as an heroku cron job to run a couple of times throughout the day. But for right now How can I get this to scrape more than one of the objects in one shot and save it to my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only goes through the loop once because of this line:

`return render(request, template, context)`

`return` returns out of the whole function altogether the first time it gets ran (in the first loop). If you want to go through each loop then return, move the `return` out of the loop like:

```
def practice(request):
    world = get_world_too()

    for entry in world:
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.save()

        template = "blog/post/noindex.html"
        context = {}

    # not in the loop anymore
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: that suggestion fixed it.  That error makes me think I should include the loop in my function. I would have probably caught that indentation and it would be cleaner. Thanks